# Manipulate output on shell script

Tags: shell

I have some output data that I would like to take just one single value into a variable. The output is like this:

```
Vin Script Sig:
Vin Tx hash:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: {"code":-1,"message":"The message"}
```

I just want to put the value from "code" into a variable. In this case the value into the variable would be -1. I was thinking a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="command to generate the output"
code=$string "some kind of filters"

echo $code
```

Answer (score 0):

Response seems to be JSON, but is wrapped with lot of text. Ideally, you will have access to the JSON only part, and then query/manipulate it with JQ. For the specific case that you provides, shell can do.  Assuming the output was captured in a file 'result-file.txt'

```
code=
while read p ; do
     if [[ "$p" == error:* ]] ; then
         code=${p#*\"code\":};
         code=${code%,*};
         break
     fi;
done <result-file.txt
```